# How do I do a second group (rank) within a set of records?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Here is an example of the data-
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVkqd.png)

First rank is done based on event_time ascending.

After the first ranking I need record 2 to record 6 be ranked as 1 and rec7 to 17 as 2. Can this be achieved in snowflake db?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the case statement and have the values as follows.

```
# I need record 2 to record 6 be ranked as 1 and rec7 to 17 as 2.

    select
        column1,
        case 
            when column1 > 2  and column1 < 6 then 1
            when column1 > 6 and column1 < 18  then '2'
             else '0'
        end as new_col
    from values (3), (4), (3), (17);
```

Comment: This is when you know what records need to be ranked. In my case, 2-6 and 7-17 is not consistent.